# Github Action can't find the local source when using dotnet restore for nuget source

Tags: .net, nuget, github-actions

I'm trying to create a github action but I need to use an internal nuget package

```
 - name: "Setup Internal Packages"
    run: |
      dotnet nuget add source ${{ secrets.artifactory_url }} \
      -n myinternalpack \
      -u ${{ secrets.artifactory_user }} \
      -p ${{ secrets.artifactory_token }} \
      --store-password-in-clear-text
```

When I run this step it says `Package source with Name: myinternalpack added successfully.`

I even make sure with the next step to list sources:

```
Run dotnet nuget list source
Registered Sources:
1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
2.  myinternalpack  [Enabled]
    ***
```

But when I try to do a restore

```
dotnet restore ./sample-app --source myinternalpack --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

It says it doesn't exist.

Comment: there's no need to specify sources on the restore command when the source has already been added to nuget.config via the `dotnet nuget add source` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I finally did was to put the nuget source credentials in a specific location.

```
dotnet nuget update source myinternalpack \
      --configfile ./nuget.config \
      -s ${{ secrets.artifactory_url }} \
      -u ${{ secrets.artifactory_user }} \
      -p ${{ secrets.artifactory_token }} \
      --store-password-in-clear-text
```

And when I did a restore, I selected where it was located.

```
dotnet restore --configfile ./nuget.config
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work you need to correct the dotnet restore step to be:

```
dotnet restore ./sample-app --source ${{ secrets.artifactory_url }} --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

The dotnet restore command allows you to define the source option as URI and not by name as stated on [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore).

> -s|--source

> Specifies the URI of the NuGet package source to use during the restore operation. This setting overrides all of the sources specified in the nuget.config files. Multiple sources can be provided by specifying this option multiple times.